# Outline detection from patterns in a list of textual articles

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, outline

Are there NLP algorithms dealing with detecting the repeating
patterns in a a list of texts from which a topic keywords
and other associative keywords can be derived?

I will show it as an example:
You have a search query "vegan food for **something** health"
(where something is a part of body you need an advice about).

The search engine will return a list of articles.

The algorithm will search for patterns in these articles.
E.g. it notices that 80 % of them have a paragraph with
at least 4 multiple instances of a word orange, similarly
carrot, apples, cucumbers.

So it will give you an outline (textual mindmap)

- orange
- carrot -->
   vitamin A
- apple
- banana -->
   vitamin B
- run a lot

Once I watched a video about semantic web on youtube and know that Tim Berners-Lee talked about something similar, but I have lost the link. Could you
keyword me to that direction again?

Comment: ngrams, skipgrams. GIYF

Comment: text clustering, topic modeling?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for `word2vec` -- described patterns can be described in terms of distance between words.